# Is there a way to make a https post with only port 80 in nginx config file?

Tags: django, nginx

So, I a have Django app which needs to send data to an API.
I am using request to send the data.
First, it was warning me that -in short- I am not using SSL for sending the JSON data.

To solve this I added "verify=PATH TO THE CERT FILE"

requests.post(url, json=payload, verify='\fullChainCert.crt')

After this I got 200, so I was happy.

Question is, will it work like this on server?

Port 443 is open on server, but only 80 in nginx config file.

Comment: Nginx can handle HTTPS on its own with the correct 443 port, so why not just use it? It can then forward the request on any port used by django, either as HTTP or HTTPS

Comment: You can use tools like [certbot](https://certbot.eff.org) to use an universal ssl/tls certificate for your nginx server. nginx by convention use port 443 for HTTPS request. you can use proxy_pass to redirect your request to any open port used by django

Comment: So, I can do something like this?


server {
    listen          80;
    server_name     localhost;
    ...
    ...
}

server {
    listen          443 ssl;
    server_name     www.example.org;
    ssl_certificate www.example.org.crt;
    ...
}



Btw, nginx add all my apps sunning in docker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure the `nginx.conf` file to work with https 443 port and redirect traffic coming to port 80 to port 443. A simple https configuration looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name yourservername.com or your_public_ip;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;   
}

server {
    listen 443 http2 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 http2 ssl;

    server_name yourservername.com or your_public_ip;
 
    # You should create the ssl certificates and use them here
    ssl_certificate        /etc/ssl/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key    /etc/ssl/private/nginx-selfsigned.key;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl   /certs/dhparam.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://django_app;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```